# How can I make the turtlebot3 walk forward through messages?

Tags: ros, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I appologize in advance for this simple question.

I would like to move the turtlebot3 ahead as described in the [Programming Robots with Ros](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/programming-robots-with/9781449325480/)  book. (The book teaches ROS programming under ros-indigo, whilst I have installed ros-noetic).

I created a package called `wanderbot` which contains an  executable called [red_light_green_light.py](https://github.com/osrf/rosbook/blob/master/wanderbot/red_light_green_light.py) to move the turtleboot ahead. The book describes the following commands to move the robot:

```
roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch
./red_light_green_light.py cmd_vel:=cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop
```

Because `tutrtlebot_gazebo` does not seem to exist in `noetic`, I replaced the commands above with

```
roslaunch turtlebot3_gazebo turtlebot3_empty_world.launch 
./red_light_green_light.py cmd_vel:=cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop
```

Unfortunately, the robot does not move an inch. What can I do to debug my code in this case?

There are three nodes active (gazebo_gui, red_light_green_light, gazebo) but the nodes are not connected. I presume the publisher in `red_light_green_light` publishes messages but no node listens.

Could somebody kindly give me some hints what to do in these cases? I am grateful for any hints and suggestions!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/356221/how-can-i-make-the-turtlebot3-walk-forward-through-messages?/) by [fabian](https://answers.ros.org/users/56325/fabian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2020-07-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2020-07-01**:
Start by looking at the list of topics printed by `rostopic`, and looking at each node with `rosnode` to see what topics they publish and subscribe to. It's likely that the turtlebot3 gazebo sim is using different topic names.

**Comment by [fabian](https://answers.ros.org/users/56325/fabian/) on 2020-07-02**:
Thank you, @Geoff for your comment - your help indeed allowed me to solve the problem! `rostopic` reveals that there is an active topic called `cmd_vel` When I bind `red_light_green_light.py` to it, the robot indeed moves.

I am wondering however how one is expected to figure that out usually? `rostopic` reveals existing topics and `rostopic info cmd_vel` shows very limited information about that topic. Is there a way for users to read more comprehensive documentation about existing topics than via `rostopic info TOPIC` ?

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2020-07-02**:
Please post your solution as an answer and then mark it as accepted, for other people who might have the same problem in the future.

I'm not sure what you mean about "more comprehensive documentation about existing topics". In general, if two nodes are not communicating and they should be the first thing you check is what they are publishing and subscribed to. It's not something you should have to do when first learning, but because you are using code not in the book you are unfortunately beyond the bounds of the tutorial it provides.

**Comment by [fabian](https://answers.ros.org/users/56325/fabian/) on 2020-07-03**:
Thanks @geoff for your comment. I wrote an answer based on your suggestions. I can't accept yet due to having too few points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks to @geoff's suggestion, I managed to solve the problem. Instead of entering

```
 roslaunch turtlebot3_gazebo turtlebot3_empty_world.launch 
 ./red_light_green_light.py cmd_vel:=cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop
```

I needed to publish to a different topic. The problem was solved by typing

```
roslaunch turtlebot3_gazebo turtlebot3_empty_world.launch 
./red_light_green_light.py cmd_vel:=cmd_vel
```

---

Originally posted by [fabian](https://answers.ros.org/users/56325/fabian/) with karma: 46 on 2020-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [HM_1991](https://answers.ros.org/users/76808/hm_1991/) on 2022-02-26**:
Worked a charm :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Published version of ROS book stated to fire up the control node using:

```
./red_light_green_light.py cmd_vel:=cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop
```

Where `cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop` was to be the topic subscribed to the `cmd_vel` node. Later Gazebo versions after publication use a new `cmd_vel` topic needing to subscribe to the publisher also named `cmd_vel`.

Therefore:

```
roslaunch turtlebot3_gazebo turtlebot3_house.launch
```

And in a new terminal:

```
./red_light_green_light.py cmd_vel:=cmd_vel
```

---

Originally posted by [tommylwalker](https://answers.ros.org/users/56918/tommylwalker/) with karma: 56 on 2020-08-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [HM_1991](https://answers.ros.org/users/76808/hm_1991/) on 2022-02-26**:
Amazing! Thank you for such a thorough explanation :D